# Where is defined this logo image in the CSS?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have this website on wich I am working on: http://onofri.org/WP_BootStrap/

and I have the following problem: using FireBug I can't find where in the CSS is definied the immage **logo.png** (that is the litle immage in the upper-left corner of the theme at the left of the main menu bar)

Can you help me? wher is it definied?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Please do not link to your web site. Here's why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0):

There you go: 
http://onofri.org/WP_BootStrap/wp-content/themes/AsperTheme/assets/img/logo.png

Easy peasy ... line 21

```
.navbar-brand {
display: inline-block;
text-indent: -9999px;
width: 190px;
height: 50px;
background: url(../img/logo.png) center center no-repeat;
}
```

How to find it out? Look at bottom right:

https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-vNhGyk3XfaY/UuFlG6ipQfI/AAAAAAAAA4w/WAkSCbMVVNE/w1042-h586-no/so.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
.navbar-brand {
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 190px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url(../img/logo.png) center center no-repeat;
}
```

http://onofri.org/WP_BootStrap/wp-content/themes/AsperTheme/assets/css/stili-custom.css?ver=all

Answer (score 0):

http://onofri.org/WP_BootStrap/wp-content/themes/AsperTheme/assets/css/stili-custom.css?ver=all

Line 21

```
.navbar-brand {
    background: url("../img/logo.png") no-repeat scroll center center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 190px;
}
```